# Popular combobox com uma lista de uma consulta

Tags: java, javafx

Bom eu tenho uma classe DAO
DepartamentosDAO
eu queria popular um combo box com uma consulta que faço nesse DAO

meu DAO:

```
public class DepartamentoDAO {

    private Connection con;

    public DepartamentoDAO() {
        this.con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }

    public boolean popularComboBox() throws SQLException{
        List<String> setores = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM departamentos";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
           setores.add(rs.getString("nome_setor"));
           }

    ps.close();
    return true;
    }
}
```

meu controller:

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox<Departamento> cbDepart;
private List<Departamento> departamentos = new ArrayList();
```

como eu conseguiria popular o meu combo box com essa lista DAO que está em outro metodo?

Answer (score 0):

uma dica seria retornar uma lista em vez de boolean:

```
public List<String> setores findAllSetores() {
        List<String> setores = new ArrayList<>();
        /*operacoes*/

        return setores;
}
```

então em qualquer outro lugar voce pode obter essa lista simplismente fazendo:

```
List<String> setores = new DepartamentoDAO().findAllSetores();
if (!setores.isEmpty()){
   /*significa que a lista nao esta vazia*/
}
```

a partir disso poderia popular sua comboBox

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
            cb.addItem();
```